# React native toggle button slow when flatlist is used

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I have component like below

```
 return (
      <View>
        <View
          style={!this.state.showSearchBar && styles.hidden}
        >
          <Header>
            <View>
              <Item >
                <Icon name="ios-search" />
                <Input placeholder="Search" />
              </Item>
              <Button
                onPress={this.searchBarButton}
              >
                <Text>Search</Text>
              </Button>
            </View>
          </Header>
        </View>

        <View
          style={this.state.showSearchBar && styles.hidden}
        >
          <Header ref={"button"}>
            <Button onPress={() => this.searchBarButton()} transparent>
              <Icon name="search" style={styles.bigblue} />
            </Button>
          </Header>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

When I click on button I basically set state so I am hiding and showing search bar with search icon

```
 searchBarButton() {
    this.setState({ showSearchBar: !this.state.showSearchBar });
  }
```

and style

```
   hidden: {
    height: 0,
    width: 0,
    opacity: 0
  }
```

So basically this works very smooth and fast when my scene is just with header , But when I add flatlist or any other big list , there is 1 second delay between toggle.Why is that so ? is it because setState is rendering whole screen ? So how can I re-render only particular component.

Comment: As far as I know, the setState method will automatically call the render method in your component. Maybe that's why you got a little bit delay.

Comment: yea how to solve this problem ?